# Woocommerce get the current value of quantity field

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I would like to know how to get the current value of quantity field in product page?
So after getting the current value, i just wanna modify the input field step. 
Example:

```
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {

    $args['input_value']    = 1
}
$args['max_value']  = 80;   // Maximum value
$args['min_value']  = 1;    // Minimum value
$args['step']       = a;    // Quantity step
```

Comment: **Official WooCommerce Documentation: 
[Adjust the quantity input values**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/) … In front end (live) you can get those values with Javascript/jQuery and you can alter steps. But if you want to send those live values to php, you will need Ajax and in this case it is an advanced development…

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec for the answer. I already seen the example. But What i want to do is : for quantity from 1 to 10 the step is 1 and from 11 to * step=10. Do you know how can implement that?